# Can we use matplotlib.animation in kivy? If Yes,How?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, kivy

Well this [How to use matplotlib animation within kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707379/how-to-use-matplotlib-animation-within-kivy) question is similar but the answer is just not at all valuable
Also as pointed by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the question to Can we actually do it?If Yes then proceed below.

So it was easy to add animation in tkinter according to the following tutorial [Sentdex tutorial on how to add matplotlib animation in tkinter](https://pythonprogramming.net/embedding-live-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/)

I tried to do the same in kivy but cannot figure out where to write the line `ani=animation.Funcanimation(blabla)` See the last line in the following code

```
class Graph(FigureCanvasKivyAgg):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        FigureCanvasKivyAgg.__init__(self,f)
        pullData = open("TimeLatitude.txt", "r").read()
        dataList = pullData.split('\n')
        xList = []
        yList = []
        pullData2 = open("TimeLongitude.txt", "r").read()
        dataList2 = pullData2.split('\n')
        xList2 = []
        yList2 = []
        for eachLine in dataList:
            if len(eachLine) > 1:
                x, y = eachLine.split(',')
                xList.append(int(x))
                yList.append(int(y))
        for eachLine in dataList2:
            if len(eachLine) > 1:
                x, y = eachLine.split(',')
                xList2.append(int(x))
                yList2.append(int(y))
        a.clear()
        a.plot(xList, yList, "#00A3E0", label="Latitude")
        a.plot(xList2, yList2, "#183A54", label="Longitude")
        a.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.02, 1, .102), loc=3,
                 ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
        title = "Oxymora Mars Rover Geographic Points\nLast Longitude : " + str(
            yList2[len(yList2) - 1]) + "\nLast Latitude : " + str(yList[len(yList) - 1])
        a.set_title(title)
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=1000)
```

Comment: The position of that line seems fine. However, is there any indication that one can run an animation with kivy?

Comment: Yes we can run an animation within kivy using garden.graph but don't know about matplotlib animation.There is no code on the web for such thing.@ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Yeah, so that is what I mean; you don't need to ask about where to put some line in the code if it is questionable if you can use it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think kivy is less used nowadays.Nobody answered So i somehow i figured out a alternative to what i wanted to achieve.
I added a Refresh button which runs the whole fuction again which includes fetching of the values from a file and draws the graph again.Thus whenever the values are updated in the file we get a plot for that.

Here's the python 3 code.

```
class Graph(FigureCanvasKivyAgg):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        FigureCanvasKivyAgg.__init__(self,f)
        pullData = open("TimeLatitude.txt", "r").read()
        dataList = pullData.split('\n')
        xList = []
        yList = []
        pullData2 = open("TimeLongitude.txt", "r").read()
        dataList2 = pullData2.split('\n')
        xList2 = []
        yList2 = []
        for eachLine in dataList:
            if len(eachLine) > 1:
                x, y = eachLine.split(',')
                xList.append(int(x))
                yList.append(int(y))
        for eachLine in dataList2:
            if len(eachLine) > 1:
                x, y = eachLine.split(',')
                xList2.append(int(x))
                yList2.append(int(y))
        a.plot(xList, yList, "#00A3E0", label="Latitude")
        a.plot(xList2, yList2, "#183A54", label="Longitude")
        a.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.02, 1, .102), loc=3,
             ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
        title = "Oxymora Mars Rover Coordinates\nLast Longitude : " + str(
            yList2[len(yList2) - 1]) + "\nLast Latitude : " + str(yList[len(yList) - 1])
        a.set_title(title)
    def animate(self):
        pullData = open("TimeLatitude.txt", "r").read()
        dataList = pullData.split('\n')
        xList = []
        yList = []
        pullData2 = open("TimeLongitude.txt", "r").read()
        dataList2 = pullData2.split('\n')
        xList2 = []
        yList2 = []
        for eachLine in dataList:
            if len(eachLine) > 1:
                x, y = eachLine.split(',')
                xList.append(int(x))
                yList.append(int(y))
        for eachLine in dataList2:
            if len(eachLine) > 1:
                x, y = eachLine.split(',')
                xList2.append(int(x))
                yList2.append(int(y))
        a.clear()
        a.plot(xList, yList, "#00A3E0", label="Latitude")
        a.plot(xList2, yList2, "#183A54", label="Longitude")
        a.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.02, 1, .102), loc=3,
                 ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
        title = "Oxymora Mars Rover Coordinates\nLast Longitude : " + str(
            yList2[len(yList2) - 1]) + "\nLast Latitude : " + str(yList[len(yList) - 1])
        a.set_title(title)
        self.draw()
```

and here's the corresponding kivy code.

```
<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        Graph
            id:gr
        Button:
            on_release: gr.animate()
            text: "Refresh"
            font_size: 15
            size_hint:0.068,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0,"top":0.8}
            color: 1,0,1,1
```

So finally after running my complete code kivy application looks like this-
[Kivy application image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX9iu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay.... so I know it's a year late, but I solved my real-time graphing problem. It seems to me that Matplotlib's FuncAnimation() method does not work with FigureCanvasKivyAgg.

Instead you have to use Kivy's Clock.schedule_interval() method, and then within the method it calls, have a line that redraws the canvas. Like this:
`self.fig.canvas.draw()`

It's not fast enough for proper real-time audio treatments. But for most typical graphing uses, it's usable.

Here's an example:

```
import queue
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from kivy.clock import Clock

class PlotInputStream():

    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.q = queue
        self.length = int((2048*2) * 44100 / (1000 * 10))
        self.plotdata = np.zeros((self.length, 1))
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.lineColour = 'blue'
        self.lines = self.ax.plot(self.plotdata, color=self.lineColour)
        # self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update_plot, interval=10, blit=False)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_plot, 1 / 60.)

    def update_plot(self, frame):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.q.get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty:
                break
            shift = len(data)
            self.plotdata = np.roll(self.plotdata, -shift, axis=0)
            self.plotdata[-shift:, :] = data
        for column, line in enumerate(self.lines):
            line.set_ydata(self.plotdata[:, column])
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        return self.lines
```

I'm plotting audio-data, but you should be able to take the same principles and plot anything. Important to note that the above is a class that gets instantiated in my Kivy app's build method. I then feed the instance into a Screen instance using:

```
self.figurecanvas = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(self.figure)
self.boxlayout_01.add_widget(self.figurecanvas)
```

That should be enough for you to get a Pyplot graph updating inside your Kivy app rather than having to rely on Matplotlib's default figure window.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is Yes,
In kivy `FigureCanvasKivyAgg` is used to display images and for display an image of **current figure** in case of matplotlib you can display by simply `return gcf()` or `return fig`

for animation you can achieved by:

`fig.canvas.draw()` this line should be added it will draw figure on canvas before return.
`fig.canvas.draw()`
`return fig`

or
`fig.canvas.draw()`
`return gcf()`

hope this help